# Live reading from iHealth device (ios - Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, health-monitoring

I want to show live measuring data from iHealth device (like iHealth app). So I implement iHealth-SDK. I can able to get User prfile data which is stored already.

```
{
HeightUnit: 0,
WeightUnit: 0,
dateofbirth: xxxxx,
gender: "Male",
height: 180.34,
logo: "https%3a%2f%2fcloud.ihealthlabs.com%2fimages%2fdefault%2fAvatar.png",
nickname: "Senthil kumar",
userid: "yyyyyyy",
weight: 29.483539113316585
}
```

I implement the corebuletooth

To deduct iHealth

```
var optionsdic : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: false, CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey)

centralManager!.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: optionsdic as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Above code call its delegate method

```
     let devID = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123"

 func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {

        if peripheral.identifier.UUIDString == devID
        {
            self.centralManager?.stopScan()
            self.myperipheral = peripheral
            self.myperipheral?.delegate = self
            self.centralManager?.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }


    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {

        if peripheral.identifier.UUIDString == devID
        {
            if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralState.Connected
            {
                var uid : CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "FF70")
                self.myperipheral = peripheral
                self.myperipheral?.delegate = self
                self.myperipheral?.discoverServices([CBUUID(string: peripheral.identifier.UUIDString)])
            }
        }
    }

 func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, error: NSError!) {
            println("Disconnected!== \(error)")
    }


    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!) {

            if let servicePeripherals = peripheral.services as? [CBService]
            {
                for servicePeripheral in servicePeripherals
                {
                    peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([servicePeripheral.UUID], forService: servicePeripheral)
                }
            }
    }



    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {

        if let charactericsArr = service.characteristics  as? [CBCharacteristic]
        {
            for charactericsx in charactericsArr
            {
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: charactericsx)

                if charactericsx.UUID.UUIDString == devID{
                    var parameter = NSInteger(1)
                    let data = NSData(bytes: &parameter, length: 1)
                    peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: charactericsx, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
                }

                if charactericsx.UUID.UUIDString == "FF70" || charactericsx.UUID.UUIDString == "FF71"{
                    var parameter = NSInteger(1)
                    let data = NSData(bytes: &parameter, length: 1)
                    peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: charactericsx, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
                    }
                peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(charactericsx)
            }
        }

    }

    func readValueForCharacteristic(Charactersic: CBCharacteristic!){
        println("character == \(Charactersic)")
    }


    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {

        if ((error) != nil) {
            println("Error discovering service: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return;
        }

        println("description: \(characteristic.description), descriptors: \(characteristic.descriptors), properties: \(characteristic.properties), service :\(characteristic.service), value:\(characteristic.value)")

        if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
            peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(characteristic)
        }
    }
```

I'm getting empty array (servicePeripherals) in didDiscoverServices method.I want to make communication between ios application and iHealth device directly. What ever data iHealth device read which is show into my application. I'm stuck with connection and read live data from iHealth device using core bluetooth.
Please advice me.

Comment: My friend, you need to post your code in order for others to fully help you

Comment: @Lamour : I edited my code. help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  Were you able to decipher how to read the iHealth Pulse Oximeter data (model PO3)?

Answer (score 0):

I've just got an Wireless Pulse Oximeter on my desk and I need to link to a Raspberry Pi or an Android (or anything, really)
It seems to me that the iHealth API is to a repository in the cloud. I do not think that the communication to the ble device is exposed in their API.

If you are still trying to get the data from these devices, as I am, maybe it is possible from observing the data exchanges between the iPhone and the ble device, but I am not sure.

If you find out, please let me know!!
John Brohan

Comment: Sorry for the comment but, have you obtained any results trying to link a Raspberry Pi to iHealth Pulse Oximeter?
I need to do the same thing, but the SDK they provide it's specifically designed for Android/iOS apps (hiding all the low-level bluetooth protocol inside static libraries or jars)